# Downvote -2 shown as +2 in achievements bar

Tags: bug

I was mildly irritated when I was deceived by the achievements bar. It showed me a green `+2`, so I clicked only to see this:

[image: Achievements Bar shows -2]

I clicked it before taking the screenshot, so I don't exactly have "proof". I'm not sure what would cause it to be a green `+2` rather than the red `-2`. This is [the relevant question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144803/moving-to-a-new-network-first-steps). (On a side note, I'm not sure why I got a downvote...)

**EDIT:** The screenshot is what I say immediately after clicking the achievements bar. I had already seen the `+10` on `How to design a home network for IoT devices?` previously.

Comment: The number in the achievement is the total since you last checked, not necessarily the number today.

Comment: @RoryAlsop That was the *only* thing that had happened since the last time I checked. You can see the previous thing was a +10 the day before that I had already seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number you see on the achievement bar before it is expanded is not the reputation you have gained today, it is the reputation change since you last checked it.

So one example of how this could happend is if you made two edits yesterday (earning you a total of +4), then get one downvote today (earning youg -2). That gives you a -2 today, but 4 - 2 = +2 since you last checked.

(This example does not exactly match the part I can see from the screenshot, so it is not the exact explanation. But there are many possible explanations for how you could have ended up with those exact numbers.)

Comment: That would make a lot of sense, but I don't see how that could be the case. See my edit.

Comment: @ZX9 Can't pinpoint exactly what happend. It might a cache issue - when you gain some rep, look at the bar, click a link and then hit back in your browser and you will see the new rep magically reappear. It might also be that something that had cost you rep (e.g. a downvoted question) was deleted, thereby giving you a rep gain with no action associated to it. So there are many possibilities, but I don't know what exactly happend in your case.

Comment: Yeah, without more information, I can't really determine anything, either. My instinct is that it was something with deletions or upvote/downvote combinations.

Comment: @ZX9 Yeah. So I think we should conclude that a bug is an unlikely culprit in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is that you have previously downvoted answers which were subsequently deleted. In that case, the downvotes cost you 1 rep each, but there is no indication after the post has been deleted *which* post deletion caused your reputation to be returned to you. Thus you can get a positive reputation change with no obvious explanation.